# Same Link opening in Loop

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am pretty new to Python and am trying to write a small code for testing links on a website.. I have created a dictionary as following:

```
header_dropdown_links = {
            'Features' : 'Features', 
            'Company' : 'Company | Values',
            'Community' : 'Community | Open Sauce',
            'Solutions' : 'Selenium Testing | Solutions',
            'Resources' : 'Resources',
            'Enterprise' : 'Enterprise',
            'Sign Up' : 'Sign Up',
            'Docs' : 'Docs',
            'Pricing' : 'Pricing',
            'Login' : 'Login'      
       }
```

The left side is the Link Name and right side is the title of the page.

I have created the following expression to find each for this link in a loop and am matching it to the title..
for link in `header_dropdown_links`:

```
header_link = '//nav[@id ="global"]//a[contains(text(),' + link + ')]'
        driver.find_element_by_xpath(header_link).click()
```

Now, when I am running this code, I am only clicking on Resources link each time but it is matching all the titles It is not clear to me why? Can someone please help me with this?

-------------------------Edited--------------------------------

I am trying to check the link which are in the Glyph(3 lines Icon).
The code I wrote:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
import unittest

header_dropdown_links = {
        'Features' : 'Features', 
        'Company' : 'Company | Values',
        'Community' : 'Community | Open Sauce',
        'Solutions' : 'Selenium Testing | Solutions',
        'Resources' : 'Resources',
        'Enterprise' : 'Enterprise',
        'Sign Up' : 'Sign Up',
        'Docs' : 'Docs',
        'Pricing' : 'Pricing',
        'Login' : 'Login'      
    }

class SauceLabsHeader(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(30)
        self.base_url = 'https://saucelabs.com/'
        self.verificationErrors = []
        self.accept_next_alert = True

    def test_sauce_labs_header(self):
        driver = self.driver

        for link in header_dropdown_links: 

            #opens SauceLabs Home Page
            driver.get(self.base_url)

            #clicks on Glyph for opening the drop down menu
            driver.find_element_by_class_name('hamburger').click()

            #finding link by xpath
            header_link = '//nav[@id ="global"]//a[contains(text(),' + link + ')]'
            driver.find_element_by_xpath(header_link).click()

            #verifying if the title matches
            expected_title = header_dropdown_links[link]
            try: self.assertRegexpMatches(driver.title,expected_title)
            except AssertionError as e: self.verificationErrors.append(str(e))


    def tearDown(self):
        self.driver.quit()
        self.assertEqual([], self.verificationErrors)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

The error I am getting:

```
   EE
======================================================================
ERROR: test_sauce_labs_header (__main__.SauceLabsHeader)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\-kuhu-\git\CS82A_Automation\src\SauceLabs_Glyph_WebDriver.py", line 42, in test_sauce_labs_header
    driver.find_element_by_xpath(header_link).click()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 232, in find_element_by_xpath
    return self.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 664, in find_element
    {'using': by, 'value': value})['value']
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 175, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 166, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
InvalidSelectorException: Message: The given selector //nav[@id ="global"]//a[contains(text(),Sign Up)] is either invalid or does not result in a WebElement. The following error occurred:
InvalidSelectorError: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //nav[@id ="global"]//a[contains(text(),Sign Up)] because of the following error:
SyntaxError: The expression is not a legal expression.
Stacktrace:
    at FirefoxDriver.annotateInvalidSelectorError_ (file:///c:/users/-kuhu-/appdata/local/temp/tmpjbvptb/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver-component.js:10245)
    at FirefoxDriver.prototype.findElementInternal_ (file:///c:/users/-kuhu-/appdata/local/temp/tmpjbvptb/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver-component.js:10276)
    at FirefoxDriver.prototype.findElement (file:///c:/users/-kuhu-/appdata/local/temp/tmpjbvptb/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver-component.js:10280)
    at DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_/h (file:///c:/users/-kuhu-/appdata/local/temp/tmpjbvptb/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12274)
    at DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_ (file:///c:/users/-kuhu-/appdata/local/temp/tmpjbvptb/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12279)
    at DelayedCommand.prototype.execute/< (file:///c:/users/-kuhu-/appdata/local/temp/tmpjbvptb/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12221)

======================================================================
ERROR: test_sauce_labs_header (__main__.SauceLabsHeader)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\-kuhu-\git\CS82A_Automation\src\SauceLabs_Glyph_WebDriver.py", line 52, in tearDown
    self.assertEqual([], self.verificationErrors)
AssertionError: Lists differ: [] != ["Regexp didn't match: 'Featur...

Second list contains 2 additional elements.
First extra element 0:
Regexp didn't match: 'Features' not found in u'Resources'

- []
+ ["Regexp didn't match: 'Features' not found in u'Resources'",
+  "Regexp didn't match: 'Enterprise' not found in u'Resources'"]

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 52.697s

FAILED (errors=2)
```

Printed valus of header_link and expected_title on the console:

```
//nav[@id ="global"]//a[contains(text(),Resources)]
Resources
//nav[@id ="global"]//a[contains(text(),Features)]
Features
//nav[@id ="global"]//a[contains(text(),Enterprise)]
Enterprise
//nav[@id ="global"]//a[contains(text(),Sign Up)]
Sign Up
//nav[@id ="global"]//a[contains(text(),Docs)]
Docs
//nav[@id ="global"]//a[contains(text(),Company)]
Company | Values
//nav[@id ="global"]//a[contains(text(),Pricing)]
Pricing
//nav[@id ="global"]//a[contains(text(),Login)]
Login
//nav[@id ="global"]//a[contains(text(),Community)]
Community | Open Sauce
//nav[@id ="global"]//a[contains(text(),Solutions)]
Selenium Testing | Solutions
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure this portion is correct -

```
header_link = '//nav[@id ="global"]//a[contains(text(),link)]'
```

Shouldn't it be -

```
header_link = '//nav[@id ="global"]//a[contains(text(),"' + link + '")]'
```

Do you want `link` as string in the contains , or do you want the text inside each link , like `Resources` there?

Comment: Can you try printing the `header_link` just before using it?

Comment: Can you please explain the significance of triple quotes over here??

Comment: its actually double quotes inside the `contains` function in xpath, without that, xpath was trying to resolve each `Resources` etc as variables rather than strings, same as it happens for any other languages

Comment: When we added the double quotes, xpath correctly started recognizing the second parameters as strings .

Answer (score 0):

Still showing error:

```
E
======================================================================
ERROR: test_sauce_labs_header (__main__.SauceLabsHeader)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\-kuhu-\git\CS82A_Automation\src\SauceLabs_Glyph_WebDriver.py", line 43, in test_sauce_labs_header
    driver.find_element_by_xpath(header_link).click()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 232, in find_element_by_xpath
    return self.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 664, in find_element
    {'using': by, 'value': value})['value']
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 175, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 166, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//nav[@id =\"global\"]//a[contains(text(),\"Sign Up\")]"}
Stacktrace:
    at FirefoxDriver.prototype.findElementInternal_ (file:///c:/users/-kuhu-/appdata/local/temp/tmpivizdh/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver-component.js:10271)
    at fxdriver.Timer.prototype.setTimeout/<.notify (file:///c:/users/-kuhu-/appdata/local/temp/tmpivizdh/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver-component.js:603)

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 94.708s

FAILED (errors=1)
```

Comment: Is the function successful for some components?

Comment: Try using the xpath - `'.//nav[@id ="global"]//a[contains(text(),"' + link + '")]'`

Comment: Sorry, it seems the solution you posted before this is working...There is some problem with finding the Sign Up...So, its failing for SIgn Up both here and the in the code you posted before..Trying to fix that..Thanks  a lot for your help! :)